# Problem Understanding Fluent nHibernate Automapping and Relationship

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, automapping

I am a bit new to Fluent nHibernate and ran into a scenario with my schema I'm not sure how to address.

Say I have two tables:

### Track

TrackId
UserId
Name

### Users

UserId
Name

Now, what I want to do is have the ability to access the related User object by track.  For example:

var track = repo.GetById(1);

var userName = track.User.Name;

How can I get nHibernate to automap this new custom User property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
public class Track
{
    public virtual int Id {get;set;}
    public virtual string Name {get;set;}
    public virtual User User {get;set;}
}

public class User
{
    public virtual int Id {get;set;}
    public virtual string Name {get;set;}
}

// Usage
var track = repo.GetById(1);
var username = track.User.Name;
```

More information can be found **[here](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Auto_mapping)**.